# Wondering how this code could turn into an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

A few week later i've done this Html parse that receive a word and counts it inside that url.  'ruby counter.rb http://abcd.com hello'

```
class Counter   

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
    end

    def count(word, url)
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      doc.css('head').remove
      doc.text.scan(/#{word}/i).size
    end
end

url, word = ARGV
puts "Found: #{Counter.new(url).count(word, url)} matches."
```

I was wondering how can i create this as a Rails JSON API only. I need to ask for :url, :word, :count, so JSON need to be built only with url, the word i asked and number of repetition that founds inside it.

I'm completely lost in how can i do this, it seems to be completely easy, but i just can't figure out.

Hope somebody helps me,
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/franzejr/creating-simple-api-with-rails-du108148l

Comment: I read this but just don't get where I put this function of mine, and what i need to rebuild to interact JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you know how to/ have created a rails application? Assuming you have done this, all you need is to define a route and map it to your controller.

```
namespace :count do 
  namespace :v1 do 
    match 'count_words', to: 'count#count_words', via: :get
  end
end
```

Then define a controller in controllers/count/v1/count_controller.rb

```
class Count::V1::CountController < ApplicationController
  def count_words
    # not sure why you're passing URL twice, but hey, whatever
    counter = Counter.new(params[:url]) 
    result = counter.count(params[:url], params[:word]
    render :json => result
  end
end
```

You're question is rather vague, but basically, I'm assuming you're passing some sort of JSON message from the front end (or external system). Rails handles the frameworky stuff for you, but all I'm doing is picking out the 'url' and 'word' sent in a JSON message like this:

```
{
  "url": "www.count.co.uk", 
  "word": "count"
}
```

Then instantiating your Counter class and passing this information to it. Then The controller is responding with a JSON message containing your counters result. You're gonna want to make sure your counter actually returns a hash structure, but this is basically all you need to do for a simple API.

To call something like this, you'd do:

```
localhost:3000/count/v1/count_words
```

Passing the above JSON message.

Comment: I want something like:  curl https://localhost:3000/v1/counter -d {"url":"http://example.com"; "word":"TesTing"}, and then it returns me a JSON with the url, the word i asked and how many words of that is inside the url

Comment: Yes, my answer would do that. The key is the route and having a controller for the API resource. All it's basically doing is taking your {"url":"example.com";; "word":"TesTing"} and passing it to your counter class, passing the result back to the requester as a JSON response. 

You need to specify an action in the URL. In my example, the action is 'count_words', but this can be configured within the route file:

app/config/route.rb

If you set up something like what I've outlined, your command would be: localhost:3000/count/v1/count_words -d {"url":"example.com", "word":"TesTing"}

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll take a look on this. Appreciate the help

Comment: No problem- don't forget to mark this as useful/ answer question if I have managed to do so =)